# Bootstrap denies js "swap css file" script?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tested this script, and it seems to work fine until I add it to my bootstrap site.

The intention is to animate the header. On bootstrap I have this all positioned as the first entry after `<body>`, immediately before `<nav>`, but I moved it around a couple times trying different stuff.  I'm pretty newbie, but I can't think of what would be excluded in the bootstrap situation.

FYI I'm loading jQuery for a slider anyways, so it's not only included for this action. It doesn't seem like a jsFiddle would help this circumstance, since it involves 2 css files, right?

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 50) {
            $('link[href="head1.css"]').attr('href','head2.css');
        } else {
            $('link[href="head2.css"]').attr('href','head1.css');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you just change the class on the required elements in your `if` condition instead of changing the `src` of a stylesheet

Comment: Why?  Also, can you think of any reason this wouldn't work on a bootsrap built scenario? Thanks.!

Comment: It's better practice as it saves loading two stylesheets (which is slower than loading one larger one) and also some browsers can have odd issues when dynamically changing stylesheets in the manner you are. There's nothing about bootstrap specifically that would affect this.

Comment: Sounds like good advice to work towards changing classes instead of stylesheets. . Thanks,  I thought I'd found a simple way to organize this task.